# Set default volume for new apps in Windows 10 mixer

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

My headphones (HyperX Cloud 2) are normally way too loud for most apps with any volume above 10%. However, I want certain apps such as Teamspeak to be 50%. The problem is new apps default to the max/master volume, which is physically painful.

Is there a way I can have new apps not default to the master volume or set apps to a volume above the master volume?

[image]