# How can I control the default volume of an application in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, default-settings

Is there a way to assign a default volume to an application when it starts?

I work from home, and I use a conference tool to talk to people in the office.  Every time I start it, it defaults to maximum volume.  If I don't quickly open the sound control panel and turn it down, it will blast the sounds of my coworkers at top volume until I do.

If I reduce the volume, close the application, then re-open it, it resets to maximum volume.  Is there a way to change that?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit.

[Slightly related.](https://superuser.com/questions/1239030/set-default-volume-for-new-apps-in-windows-10-mixer)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 , there is a facility to use custom volumes for individual apps which is **Volume Mixture**  option which can be accessed by  right-clicking on the volume icon to bring up the menu which has the option. You can even use Ear Trumpet which is a freeware for windows for the purpose specified by you.

More information and other methods can be found in the [Link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/adjust-volume-for-individual-programs-windows).

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for this - I have tried the Volume Mixer.  Using that, I can adjust the volume of just my noisy app, and it works fine.  The problem is, that if I quit the app, then start it again, it always reverts to maximum volume, and I have to set it again.  Do you know a way to automatically define a default volume?

Comment: Have you tried **Ear Trumpet** which I mentioned ? you can refer the link provided.

Comment: I tried it today, and I like it a lot; the user interface is an improvement over the Windows audio.  However, it does not "remember" the volume setting between launches.  If I lower the volume, close the app, then relaunch, it still goes back to 100.  Thanks for the tip though.